# Memory issue in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am saving images in database and also using av capture session for creating custom    camera.   but as I save more and more images in database it gives memory warnings.

when i stop saving images to database the the app works fine why is it happening? Does it happen due to increase in size of database ?

Current code:

```
-(void)insert
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbsqlite.sqlite"];

    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        ////////\\

        for (jk=0; jk<[globalvalue count];jk++)
        {


            NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation((UIImage *)[globalvalue objectAtIndex:jk]);




            const char *query = "insert into color(img) values (?)";

            sqlite3_stmt *searchStatement2;



            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query, -1, &searchStatement2, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                sqlite3_bind_blob(searchStatement2,1, [imgData bytes], [imgData length], NULL);
                if (sqlite3_step(searchStatement2) == SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    NSLog(@"saved");
                }

    //
    //          while (sqlite3_step(searchStatement2) == SQLITE_ROW)
    //          {
    //              NSString *name2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement2, 0)];
    //              NSString *category2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement2, 1)];
    //              NSLog(@"%@ is a %@ color", name, category);
    //
    //
    //            }
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(searchStatement2);
        }
    }

    [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"alert" message:@"your query saved" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
    sqlite3_close(database);
}

- (void)makeDBCopyAsNeeded
{
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbsqlite.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success)
    {
        return;
    }
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbsqlite.sqlite"];

    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success)
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}

-(void)readFromDatabase
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbsqlite.sqlite"];


    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *sqlStatement="select img,rowID from color";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {

                NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement,0) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement,0)];
                if(data == nil)
                    NSLog(@"No image found.");
                else
                {
                    UIImage *personImage= [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    NSString *rowid1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement,1)];
                    [rowid addObject:rowid1];
                    [arrImageFromDataBase addObject:personImage];

                    //                NSData *data       = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, 4) length:length];
                    NSLog(@"%@",personImage);
                }

            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSLog(@"contents of array%@",rowid);
}
```

It's a bit confusing ...sorry for inconvenience but really need help!!

Comment: do you use ARC ? cleaned up your English.

Comment: storing an image in database is not proper approach.

Comment: so what to do. as my app has a provision for editing the images that is saved by user in its personal gallery so that he/she can edit it any time again

Comment: try to store the image in user's Documents folder.

Comment: How are you using `globalvalue`?

Comment: the image gets saved in a global variable. As image comes from other view and then its get executed in query.

Comment: Another advice. Don't copy database from sandbox to documents. On next update your app will be rejected due the new rules in HIG. This happend to my app. The better approach is to keep file.sql file with your sql queries that suppose to create the db in doc folder in sandbox and execute it if needed.

Comment: Its just that image comes from 2nd view stored in global variable and gets executed in 1st view as query. Do U got the logic?

Comment: Save images to the documents folder and save the image path in db.

Comment: Anil is right. I do the same way.

Comment: okk i l try that. one thing more does av capture session also give memory warnings while the image is clicked multiple times?

Comment: i am now saving images in documents directory instead of database.but still i recieve memory warning . why its happening? because of size of images or something else

Answer (score 1):

As written by others, it's not a good idea to store images in the DB. But this is not the problem :-)

I see that you have a for loop.
Are there warnings happening when you insert multiple images at the same time?
Or they happens even if you insert the images "one by one"?

In the first case, consider this:

You have `UIImagePNGRepresentation` inside the for loop.
This function returns an autoreleased NSData.
The autorelease pool is purged only at the end of the current run loop (when the program stops waiting for the next action by the user, for example).
So, all NSData created by that function are kept alive untile the run loop ends.

For this reason, if you insert 10 images at one time, you are copying in memory 10 NSData that will be purged only at the end of the computation.
If you insert 100 image, same story.

Use Instruments - Allocation tool to check if this is the case (you will see memory occupied by NSData increasing during the loop, and immediately decreasing when the computation is finished). If true, you can solve creating a specific autorelease pool.

with this, the specific autorelease pool is purged at each loop

```
for (jk=0; jk<[globalvalue count];jk++)
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation((UIImage *)[globalvalue objectAtIndex:jk]);




        const char *query = "insert into color(img) values (?)";

        sqlite3_stmt *searchStatement2;



        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query, -1, &searchStatement2, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_blob(searchStatement2,1, [imgData bytes], [imgData length], NULL);
            if (sqlite3_step(searchStatement2) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                NSLog(@"saved");
            }

            //
            //          while (sqlite3_step(searchStatement2) == SQLITE_ROW)
            //          {
            //              NSString *name2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement2, 0)];
            //              NSString *category2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement2, 1)];
            //              NSLog(@"%@ is a %@ color", name, category);
            //
            //
            //            }
        } sqlite3_finalize(searchStatement2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to save the image into the library you can use the following code:

`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo);`

then save the Library path into your sql database.
This will reduce the size in the db. also you can resize the image to show in the image view
so that your memory usage reduces.

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image 
           scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
   [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
   UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Its is very obvious if you will save more and more of images in database it will give memory warning.Because its create a copy of the image and saving it in database.

Just save the image in library and save there path in database or plist.

Comment: It's not "very obvious". Even if it's not a good idea to store images inside a database, this won't cause the issue described by the OP. You can save "more and more" images into the database, if you know the basics of memory management rules you won't have problem and memory warnings.

Comment: and yes, using ARC it's not a good reason to forget memory management rules :-) they are still important